# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pexpect'

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, centos7, pexpect

My python script is throwing error while trying to import pexpect

```
python3 amf_bringup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "amf_bringup.py", line 1, in <module>
import pexpect
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pexpect'
```

I have already installed pexpect

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pexpect
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pexpect) (0.7.0)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Tested pexpect.run (4.8) in CentOS 7.9, using Python 3.6.8, and everything worked. Can you show us some code? If not:
- Check your shebang; it should read `#!/usr/bin/python3`
- Check your PYTHONPATH: `echo $PYTHONPATH`
- Try reinstalling python: `yum install python36`

Comment: pexpect was installed under Python 3.6 & my python3 was Python 3.8. Just added 3.6 path to PYTHONPATH & it worked. Thanks